# How to align table inside a div limits

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I've added a table to a div with CSS stylesheet file and my table is going out of the div`s limits.
I think that because of the drop-boxes the width isn't taking the div's limits.

What should I do to fix this?

My table in aspx:

```
<asp:Table ID="TblRFADetails" runat="server"> 
     <asp:TableHeaderRow>
         <asp:TableHeaderCell></asp:TableHeaderCell>
     </asp:TableHeaderRow>
     <asp:TableRow>
          <asp:TableCell> 
           <asp:DropDownList ID="injuredSectorDD" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceProject16" DataTextField="Sector_name" DataValueField="Sector_id" /> 
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceProject16" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:igroup13_test1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Sector]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
  </asp:TableCell> </asp:TableRow></asp:Table>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I see no div in your code, however if your css is setting a width on the div and the DDL is wider than the div, then yes it will exceed the bounds, you can:

1. set css on the div to set `overflow:hidden` which will hide any part of the DDL that oversteps it's bounds
2. remove the width on the div and let the DDL control width
3. place a width on the DDL, to keep within the width of the div.

Regardless of the width of the text box portion of the DDL, the actually drop down popup will likely display as wide as the widest element in the list.

Comment: ok, well now i see that my thought was right and the DDL are the ones that making it so big...  though i dont know how to do a class only for them in my css...

Comment: ASP.NET controls have a CssClass property that can be set at design time or run time or even by js/jquery on the client side.